# Has anyone experience migrating Spring JSP + JS based application toward react?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, reactjs, migration

The frameworks we use in the application are Spring+JSP on backend, and custom-made JS page based scripts with home-standardized displaying components on front end. This works good for the moment but we need faster development time and better handling of customizing user UX. We are fully separated betwen both worlds using only an API.
I'm looking at react as a better way to handle customer requirements but I don't know how/where to start. Does anyone has experience/pointers towards a successfull experience in such matters?

Answer (score 1):

I am rebuilding a Spring JSP application in React in a modular fashion.  Replacing JSP pages with React components . Loading them in the DOM by injecting them in the footer or header JSP page for now.

Comment: So no separation at the moment between a frontend project and the spring web project?